# Missing NICs in a HP ProLiant DL380 G6 running RHEL 5.5 64-bit

Tags: hp-proliant, rhel5, nic

I have 2 twin boxes HP ProLiant DL3680 G6 running RHEL 5.5 64-bit. In one of them, two network interfaces (eth2 and eth7) are missing, i.e., they are not available:

```
# ifconfig eth2
eth2: error fetching interface information: Device not found
# ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available
```

I've found differences in the output of the "lspci -v" command for one up-and-running NIC and the missing ones. Here you can read the output and note the differences:

```
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC382i Integrated Quad Port PCI Express Gigabit Server Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 170
        Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at e6310000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] Message Signalled Interrupts: 64bit+ Queue=0/4 Enable-
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Mask- TabSize=9
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint IRQ 0
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 50-75-4b-fe-ff-55-26-00
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 210
        Memory at fb2c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] Message Signalled Interrupts: 64bit+ Queue=0/3 Enable-
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Mask- TabSize=1
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint IRQ 0
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
```

Pay attention on the missing string of description "(rev 20)", in the disabled "Memory" line and in the serial number reported.

Do you think it is a hardware problem?
Perhaps the NICs have been misflashed and their ROMs are not properly updated?

Thanx in advance

Update 2014-07-28

Lawrence requested me to show the dmesg output. The following lines have been found in the dmesg output:

```
ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:03:00.0[A] -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 210
PCI: Setting latency timer of device 0000:03:00.0 to 64
bnx2 0000:03:00.0: Firmware not running, aborting.
ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:03:00.0 disabled

ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:03:00.1[B] -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 218
PCI: Setting latency timer of device 0000:03:00.1 to 64
bnx2 0000:03:00.1: Firmware not running, aborting.
ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:03:00.1 disabled
```

I never updated the firmware of these NICs.

Comment: Have you updated your system firmware?

Comment: Can you also paste the `dmesg` output for the server ?

Comment: No, ewwhite, I never updated the firmware of this box.